# Is empty set the power set of any subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Is empty set the power set of any subset?

I know that cardinality of a set is less than cardinality of power set, so if empty set is that power set of some set, then that set would have cardinality less than $0$, which is not possible.

However, my problem is this:

> Let $A$ be the set and $P(A)$ denote power set of $A$. 
>   Then $x \in P(A) \implies x \subseteq A.$
>
> By this, $\emptyset $ should be a power set of everything.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: $x\in P(A)$ implies $x\subset A$

Comment: $ x \in A \to x \subseteq A$  is true when $A$ is the empty set, but so what?

Comment: I corrected my error, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that, for a given $A$, $P(A)$ contains *exactly* those sets that are a subset of $A$. It follows from the definition of "subset" that the empty set is a subset of absolutely everything, including $A$, and therefore $P(A)$ must have at least $\emptyset$ as a member, making it non-empty. But $A$ was arbitrary, so it follows that *no* powerset is empty.

Answer (score 7):

If $A$ is any set then $\emptyset \in P(A)$ (since $\emptyset\subseteq A$) hence $P(A)\neq \emptyset$